# Change edittext text color android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can you change the edittext text color AFTER it is entered in android? (Take an input, and on the press of a button, change the color of the contents of the edittext!)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to change the color of all of the text, you can [call `setTextColor()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29) on the `EditText`.

If you are looking to change the color of some of the text, you can apply a `ForegroundColorSpan` to that text. `getText()` on an `EditText` should return a `SpannableStringBuilder`, on which you can call `setSpan()` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onButtonClick(View v){
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Button Click You can use one of the following :

- ```
  editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
  ```
- ```
  editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
  ```
- ```
  editText.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
  ```
- ```
  editText.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0));
  ```
- ```
  editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.editTextColor));
  ```
- ```
  editText.setTextColor(0xAARRGGBB);
  ```